# How to install App to test iPad to reproduce deployment

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, installation, ipa

i created an "IPA" file to try my IOS App on the iPad before deploying to the apple store.

Once i export the "IPA" from Xcode and import it in iTunes , the app appears on the iPad semi-transparent and even after selecting "instal" in iTunes, it won't start.

Every time you tap on the icon , it says "installing" but it will not install it...
I tried to sync several times but without any success..
What am I doing wrong???

Thank you in advance

Comment: What provisioning profile have you used to sign the IPA that you've tried? Is the iPad that you're trying to test on, provisioned on that profile?

Comment: Hi , thanks , the iPad is a test iPad, and it is provisioned. it is working in a normal environment when i use Xcode for release version,etc...

Comment: I ran into this once and, IIRC, it was because there were required device capabilities that weren't satisfied by the device I installed it on.

Comment: it is really weird ,because it installs it but the icon remains semi-transparent... i tried to install even the same version that  is on the apple store and, the one from the apple store works and the one i load locally does not allow any interaction...is there any other software from apple that can load an app on the iPad? maybe iTunes is not the best way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

1. go developer.apple.com
2. in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles section. Create a provisioning profile for your app.
3. add your ipad's udid to that profile.
4. install profile
5. drag and drop that profile to itunes

and did what you wrote above. Good luck.

edit: if problem continues check ipad's profiles. (settings - general - profiles)